# Connection from origin https://remix.ethereum.org rejected

Tags: remix

I was trying to share my local folder of contracts to remix-ide using RemixD.
I followed the tutorial [here](https://remix.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial_remixd_filesystem.html). I ran the code below which is how you setup the connection for remixd and remix-ide now.

```
remixd -s D:\remix-contract --remix-ide https://remix.ethereum.org/#optimize=true&version=soljson-v0.4.25+commit.59dbf8f1.js
```

After that it shows

```
setup notifications for D:\remix-contract
Thu Nov 08 2018 11:40:24 GMT+0800 (China Standard Time) Remixd is listening on 127.0.0.1:65520
```

But when I click on the link icon on remix-ide, it won't connect.
[image: remix-ide-img]

And prompts `Connection from origin https://remix.ethereum.org rejected.` in my cmd. Am I missing some setup/configuration that I need to do to succefully connect my local folder to remix-ide using remixd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found that the fault is at the url of the remix-ide. It should only be `remixd -s D:\remix-contract --remix-ide https://remix.ethereum.org`

Answer (score 0):

What i have observed is as long you are using with secured http (i.e., https) you won't see `Connection from origin http://remix.ethereum.org rejected.`
But if you have written the contracts with remix loaded as a simple http and trying to connect to that instance using remixd then we will observe that the connection is rejected.

Also, you have to specify the entire url of the remix ide instance that is being currently used like

> http://remix.ethereum.org/#optimize=false&version=soljson-v0.5.0+commit.1d4f565a.js

Remember that the same url with https as below would not load any previously written contracts from local storage

> https://remix.ethereum.org/#optimize=false&version=soljson-v0.5.0+commit.1d4f565a.js

Answer (score 0):

The reason is in typo: You (and I) had http**s**, but need http.

[image]