# Remix not getting connected to local

Tags: remix, ide

I have been trying to connect remix to my machine and I have tried the following command:

`remixd -s ./contracts --remix-ide http://remix.ethereum.org`

Also, I have tried the `https` and other combinations which are mentioned [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/61941/connection-from-origin-https-remix-ethereum-org-rejected/61945)
but, still I have not been able to connect to the remix and sometimes it shows me `Connection from origin http://remix.ethereum.org rejected.` but sometimes it doesn't mention if it has been connected to the remix or not.

I have tried both the old and new version of remix but the problem persists on both.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should try http**S**://remix.ethereum.org instead then

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 important things :

1 - You should check the URL to be http://remix.ethereum.org

( Careful the address shouldn't have http**S**:// )

2 - Also you must to change the local address from http://127.0.0.1:8545
**TO**   http://0.0.0.0:8545